# Error installing r package code tools

Tags: r

Im trying to update the codetools package and get the same error is I use update.package() or install.package(), as shown below.  Any insight is appreciated:

```
R> install.packages("codetools", lib = "/usr/lib/R/library")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/codetools_0.2-14.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 12938 bytes (12 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 12 KB

* installing *source* package ‘codetools’ ...
** package ‘codetools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
mv: cannot move ‘/usr/lib/R/library/codetools’ to ‘/usr/lib/R/library/00LOCK-codetools/codetools’: Permission denied
Warning in file.copy(f, instdir, TRUE) : problem copying ./NAMESPACE to /usr/lib/R/library/codetools/NAMESPACE: Permission denied
Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open file '/usr/lib/R/library/codetools/DESCRIPTION': Permission denied
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package ‘codetools’
* removing ‘/usr/lib/R/library/codetools’
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘codetools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpiJWb8L/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Warning in install.packages : cannot create file '/usr/share/R/doc/html/packages.html', reason 'Permission denied'
Warning in install.packages : cannot update HTML package index
```

Comment: Here's my suggestion: If you have the permission to do so, delete the folder `/usr/lib/R/library/00LOCK-codetools/` and trt again.

Answer (score 5):

*Permission denied* sounds like you don't have administrator permission on that system. Try running R as root (or with `sudo`) and see if it works then.